# How can I replay more destruction in Red Faction Guerilla?

Tags: xbox-360, onlive, red-faction-guerrilla

I enjoyed playing through the story in Red Faction Guerilla back when it came out but now I'm mostly interested in going back and just laying waste to buildings with explosives and the nanorifle. The game sort of prevents you from doing this in a couple ways: after the story is finished, you can go back and play missions you already completed but buildings don't respawn unless they're specifically part of a mission. If I simply start a new game, I'm left with weapon restrictions and (sigh) no jetpack.

How can I go back and have fun destroying buildings again in this game? It doesn't seem like there are any cheats that would let me run around and destroy things - no storyline attached - which is exactly what I want to do. I've got the 360 version and the onlive version, so a solution on either platform will work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Play the game on its easiest difficulty setting. This is actually just as fun, if not funner, than messing about with the nanorifle - as this option has a storyline, goals and play length, while still allowing you to randomly take out buildings and do whatever you want, whenever you please.

Comment: I don't get what you are saying, easiest difficulty setting (which is "casual") doesn't change anything, I still have no jetpack or any advance weapons in the beginning and the building doesn't respawn.